# redirect subdomain and retain url structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I'm redirecting a wordpress blog that lived in a subdomin to my root.  when i visit links from my old blog, they just redirect to the index page of my blog, but i need them to redirect to the actual post.  for example -

```
sub.mysite.com/1/2/3 - should redirect to -  mysite.com/sub/1/2/3
```

how can this be done?  thanks!

UPDATE - still haven't found a solution for this.  Anyone?

OR is there another post here that already exists that will show me the correct way to do this?  THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative approach is by editing your web server configuration.

Apache's [rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) can do this. You most likely have a .htaccess file in the root directory of your blog. Append the text below to it. If there is no such file, create one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.mysite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/sub$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Your web server has to be configured to accept this configuration from a .htaccess file. It can also be placed in the configuration directly. The procedure for this differs depending on your web host.

Comment: thanks so much.  i tried the .htaccess method you mentioned, but the old link still redirects to mysite.com/sub (the root - not the full url).

i setup the subdomain initially in my hosting control panel.  originally i pointed it to a subfolder, and now I'm pointing it to mysite.com/sub.  could that be causing it to always go to the root and not the original post?

Comment: More likely the web server is not accepting these new rules. Usually you need to restart the web server. If the hosting company has disallowed it, you're out of luck too. I just tested the rules I wrote, they do work.~$ curl -I sub.mysite.com/1/2/3
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://mysite.com/sub/1/2/3

Comment: ok, i reset my subdomain settings on my hosting to point to root.  now the rule you posted above does redirect mysite.com/sub to sub.mysite.com, but does not retain the full urls.

for example if someone goes to sub.mysite.com/1/2/3 the get a 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wordpress Redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) should be able to do exactly what you need.

If it doesn't, you can also accomplish this using your web server's configuration, but it's more complex to set up. See my second answer on this page.

Comment: i tried using the redirection plugin before implementing your rule and it did work, but it did not retain the full urls. for example if someone goes to sub.mysite.com/1/2/3 the get a 404 error.

Comment: I second this approach. You can use a regex to match the path part of the URL and insert it into the new URL. e.g. Source URL: https://sub.example.com/(.*)$ Target URL: https://example.com/$1