# Redirecting subdomains to wordpress content

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have one single Wordpress application on domain www.mywpsite.com.

I have static pages:

```
a. www.mywpsite.com/subsite
b. www.mywpsite.com/subsite/child1
c. www.mywpsite.com/subsite/child2
```

and need that content to be respectively addressed using a subdomain like this:

```
a. subsite.mywpsite.com
b. subsite.mywpsite.com/child1
c. subsite.mywpsite.com/child2
```

Note that there is no physical structure for the subdomain, it is just a way of aliasing, and there is only one Wordpress installation under one document root. Also, I have a few pages and just one subdomain to work with, so a 'case by case' solution is valid.

Eventually I will also use the same subdomain for some dynamic content:

```
d. www.mywpsite.com/category/subsitenews => subsite.mywpsite.com/news
```

Finally, if possible, I need that the url retained in the address bar is the one using the subdomain, I mean:

1. The user types subsite.mywpsite.com/some-static-or-dynamic-content.
2. Redirection is performed to the appropriate wordpress content, and content is delivered.
3. The url in the user is still the same using subdomain, instead of the redirected url.

How can I do this?

I think I must use .htaccess but I have no idea how it works. I'm not sure if other questions I have found have to do with my problem.

[redirect subdomain and retain url structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475249/redirect-subdomain-and-retain-url-structure)

[.htaccess redirect ~ [fake-subdomain.domain.com/*] to [domain.com/*]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353139/htaccess-redirect-fake-subdomain-domain-com-to-domain-com)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If the subdomain's aren't on the same server and under the same document root as the main domain, then you'll need to use a reverse proxy, or the `P` flag using mod_rewrite. You can try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any rules that may already be there:

```
RewriteEngine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ http://$1.mywpsite.com/$2 [L,P]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ http://$1.mywpsite.com/ [L,P]
```

The problem here is that dynamic content, ones that wordpress dynamically generates, will also be sent to the subdomains. There is no way to tell on the htaccess level what's valid dynamic content and what isn't. In order to check for that, you'll need to do it from within the wordpress CMS, probably some way of doing that but it'll require custom code or at least a plugin and possible customizing the plugin.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I have edited the question and providing more information. I can use a "case by case" redirection, including the only one case of dynamic content I have and improving performance, maybe. I'll try the rules and will let you know, as soon as I gain access to .htaccess.

Comment: @AntonioSánchez if it's case by case, you can replace the `^/?([^/]+)` in the regex with `^/(subsite)` or whatever the subdomain's name is.